# Delete rows from binding source with foreign key

Tags: vb.net, datatable, sql-delete

I have a DataSource with 2 tables one projectDiamter and other diameterSet. ProjectDiameter id contains primary key and diameterset has foreign key constraint with same key.

Now when I select row from projectdiameter table diameterset DataGridView get filtered accordingly. I have lots of rows in diameterset (lets say 15000 for selected project only) which I want to delete when delete button is pressed.

I wanted to know which is the fastest way to delete it from DataGridView and SQL table.

I tried following code but wanted to check if there is any better way of getting the same.

```
FKProjectDiameterBindingSource.MoveFirst()
For j As Int16 = 0 To FKProjectDiameterBindingSource.Count - 1
    For i As Int16 = 0 To FKDiameterDiameterSetBindingSource.Count - 1
        FKDiameterDiameterSetBindingSource.Clear()
        FKDiameterDiameterSetBindingSource.MoveFirst()
        FKDiameterDiameterSetBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    Next
    FKProjectDiameterBindingSource.MoveNext()
Next

Me.Validate()
DiameterTableAdapter.Update(RSM3DDB1.Diameter)
DiameterSetTableAdapter.Update(RSM3DDB1.DiameterSet)
```

Comment: What is diameter in this context?

Comment: sorry for confusion diameter is the main table(i.e. project as said earlier) and diameterset is the one with foreign key constraint. i have edited accordingly

Comment: Are you trying to do the equivalent of this SQL `DELETE FROM [DiameterSet] WHERE ProjectID = @projectid`, and have the change reflected on your UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the foreign key relationship exist formally in the database? That is, is there an actual relationship defined in SQL? If so, I'd suggest setting that relationship to CASCADE DELETE and then all you have to do is call DiameterSetTableAdapter.UPDATE after you update Diameter.

A good explanation on CASCADE DELETE is here 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2365/sql-server-foreign-key-update-and-delete-rules/ Note that the keyword is just "Cascade" but you apply it to DELETE, the article explains ("It is not necessary that the same rule be applied for both update and delete operations. There may be different rules for each of the update and delete operations on a single FK constraint.")

If the relationship isn't formal, that is it logically exists but isn't enforced, then I'd put a trigger on the Diameter table and in that trigger delete all the rows in DiameterSet where the DiameterID equals the  deleted DiameterID. Note that in a trigger a row that is modified (as opposed to deleted) will be in both the INSERTED and DELETED temporary tables, so you have to take steps to make sure you're not removing rows that reference a modified Diameter.

If you take this second approach, you can still just run the 2 UPDATE procedures on the 2 table adapters in VB, it's just more coding in SQL than setting the CASCADE DELETE.

Both approaches are MUCH more efficient than doing it in VB, and it can add up if you have hundreds of rows affected.

Using either of these also has the advantage of being atomic, whereas your approach is not.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.... implemented cascade at one instance and working like a charm.... the only thing is I wanted to delete only child table entries with specific key selected in parent table(datagridview row) is there any way with cascade i can delete child table rows but keep in parent table please?

Comment: You can easily do that, though not with CASCADE, just execute a SQL query that deletes all the rows with that DiameterID. In SQL Create a Stored Procedure that takes DiameterID as a parameter and in the body deletes all rows in DiameterSet with that DiameterID. In VB, create a QueryTableAdapter (or add to an existing one) and add a call to that StoredProcedure, then in your code after the Me.Validate create an instance of that QueryTableAdapter and use it to call the stored procedure. Then use your table adapter's FILL method to reload the data. Out of space, should I expand this in answer?